# How to change label value by onClick envent from a select box

Tags: javascript

I have a web form like this:

```
<form id="gopro-form" method="post">
  <select name="plan" class="plan-options">
    <option value="0">Value 0</option>
    <option value="1">Value 2</option>
  </select>
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
     data-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-description="Access for a year"
     data-amount="0"
     data-image="images/slogo.png"
     data-locale="auto">
  </script>
  <a onclick="{$go_pro_action}"><img style="position: absolute;" src="/themes/vive/images/paypal.gif"></a>
</form>
```

I need a JavaScript code so that when I change the select box that contains `value="0"` and `value="1"` it changes the data in: `data-amount="300"` automatically. Also, the default value is `data-amount="0"`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your question? Or are you just asking us to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to check the value of selected option.

Add id to your select

```
 <select id="plan-options_id" name="plan" class="plan-options">
```

Also create a variable data-amount and initialize with default 0 value

```
var data-amount = 0;

if($( "#plan-options_id option:selected" ).val() == 1 ){
   data-amount = 300;
}
```

And replace the var to your script data;

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to add a value to your data attr:

```
$( ".plan-options" ).change(function() {
  if($( "#plan-options_id option:selected" ).val() == 1 ){
     $('.stripe-button').data('amount', 100);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to `onchange` of the dropdown.

```js
function changeValue(e) {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName('stripe-button')[0];  
  el.dataset.amount = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value == "1" ? 300 : 0;
}
```

```html
<form id="gopro-form" method="post">
        <select name="plan" class="plan-options" onchange="changeValue(this)">
            <option value="0">Value 0</option>
            <option value="1">Value 2</option>
        </select>
        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            data-description="Access for a year"
            data-amount="0"
            data-image="images/slogo.png"
            data-locale="auto">
        </script>
        <a onclick="{$go_pro_action}"><img style="position: absolute;" src="/themes/vive/images/paypal.gif"></a>
    </form>
```